# Mapping relationships for One to Many and a new column addition

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mapping

I have two tables Player and Match. I need a OnetoMany relationship between Player and Match so that the JSON output which i get is like this:-

```
{
     id : 1,
     name : "Peter",
     nationality: "Indian",
     matches: [
                    {
                       id : 1,
                       location: "Mohali"
                       TournamentName: "FA Cup"
                    },
                    {
                       id : 2,
                       location: "Kolkata"
                       TournamentName: "ISL league"
                    }
             ]
}
```

Can you please suggest how to define the annotations and get the above result? I have code written like this:-

```
@Entity
public class Match {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="match_id")
    private Integer mId;

    private String seriesName;

    private String location;

    @ManyToOne
    private Player player;
```

and the Player is like this :-

```
@Entity
public class Player {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="player_id")
    private Integer pId;

    private String pName;

    private String cricketTeam;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "player" ,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Match> matches;
```

Apart from this , I also need to have an additional attribute in my result JSON which is :-

```
totalGoals: 8
```

This attribute will calculate the total number of goals scored by a player in each match , so there has to be a new table with columns :- "player_id" , "match_id" and "totalGoal"

It would be very helpful if you can provide a good approach to it

Answer (score 2):

For your first problem I don't think you need to do any extra efforts try to use Player as return object to the RestController(I would prefer DTO as returning object like PlayerDTO as you can have custom changes according to requirement)

```
@RequestMapping<!--mapping--!>
public ResponseEntity<Player> getPlayer(<expected Params as playerId>)
{
    return ResponseEntity.ok(service.find(id));
}
```

For second question you can maintain a parameter totalGoals in match object itself you don't need another mapping table until unless you have other requirement

Comment: I have the requirement for which i have to maintain a third join table where i have player_id , match_id and total goals column

Comment: Also for the first, i am getting an error which is :-
" You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near"

Comment: Are you using any predefined CrudRepository method or have you written your own customized query?